# Fetch from DB asynchronously in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an application that starts from a login route, checks credentials against a backend, fetches user information asynchronously from either the backend or offline storage and then transitions to another route where that user information is used to format a date.
The problem lays when I refresh the page once logged in. The settings are lost and falls back to default formatting.

Code for fetching the user information is inside a service and returns a promise.

```
fetchUserInfo: ->
  new Ember.RSVP.Promise (resolve) =>
    settings = @get('store').find 'settings'
    @set 'settings', settings
    resolve(settings)
```

My question is, when I refresh the webpage where should I place this fetching code again, is it good practice to just put it in **init** in the controller?

Comment: You probably should use the `model` hook to fetch your data.

Comment: Not possible. Solved it with observers.

Comment: Why not possible? Then use a simple CP.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you look into Ember Simple Auth, as it handles storage of that type of info in local storage for you automatically.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank yoy

Comment: Sure! Also, by the way, observers are considered harmful (there was a talk about it last summer by Stef Penner), so would suggest you only use them as a last resort